# Accessing a variable from Activity inside static nested fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my activity I have a TextView and I want to set text from static nested DialogFragment. Here is my code

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static MainActivity instance;

public MainActivity() {
    instance = this;
}


public void setText(final String text){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(text)
        }
    });
}
```

Use it like this

```
MainActivity.instance.setText("1234");
```

But I advise you to stay away from static instances, and use a listener (callback) instead!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any static variables or any thing that could cause you a memory leak. You can implement the listener on the activity and assign it upon fragment attaching. This is the documented way of how should fragments communicate with its activity and other fragments.

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
   private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mCallback;
   @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       super.onAttach(activity);

       // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
       // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
       try {
           mCallback = (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) activity;
       } catch (ClassCastException e) {
           throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                   + " must implement DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener");
       }
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), mCallback, year, month, day);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution of my problem:: 
I just added static modifier before textview variable inside Activity.